# Solr Suggester suggestions with match on position 1 should be scored higher than position 2

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I'm using Solr 7.1 and I'm trying to create a Solr Suggester which will suggest brand names. For brand names that exist of multiple words this should work too. A requirement is that the position of the word in the brand name is important. If it's closer to the start of the suggestion the "score" should be higher. There is also an extra "weight" to score certain brand names higher too.

*Brands*

- Dutch Foo
- Foo Tech (weight: 2)
- Foo Inc
- American Foo
- Foobar

Searching for "foo" should result in these suggestions:

1. Foo Tech
2. Foo Inc
3. Foobar
4. American Foo
5. Dutch Foo

Brand names where *Foo* is on position 2 are scored lower. And *Foo Tech* is scored on top because of the extra weight.

My setup (I tried it on multiple machines) does not work consistently. On one system I did get the correct results after many tries, but it wasn't clear to me why...

I configured this `searchComponent`:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">brandNameSuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">brandName</str>
        <str name="weightField">weight</str>
        <str name="payloadField">id</str> <!-- here for testing purposes -->
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">brandNameSuggest</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

I used `BlendedInfixLookupFactory` of it's ability to regard the position.

The fieldtype `brandNameSuggest` is simple and defined as follows:

```
<fieldType name="brandNameSuggest" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
         <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The field `brandName` is like this:

```
<field name="brandName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I query like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mycore/suggest?suggest.dictionary=brandNameSuggester&suggest.build=true&suggest.q=foo

Changing the `dictionaryImpl`

```
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
```

To:

```
<str name="dictionaryImpl">HighFrequencyDictionaryFactory</str>
```

Does make it work (I'm not sure why). But then `weightField` is disregarded. And I don't want that.

Any tips how to make this work? I need both the position and the weightfield.

Comment: I think I figured out what was "wrong". The setup is in fact correct, but the values of the "weightfield" were left to null or 0 in my database (which I imported with DIH). When I give the weight a default value of 1 it works.